# Get term link of shared taxonomy between multiple post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Let's say that we have three `custom post types`: museum, theater and restaurant that share the same `hierarchical taxonomy`: location

Up till now I have 3 different urls for each of cpt archive pages:
/museum/location/city-a
/theater/location/city-a
/restaurant/location/city-a
and single pages for custom posts with urls like:
/museum/national-museum

What I want is to get the link of the relevant term on both the archive and single pages of the other two custom post types. So if we are on page */museum/location/city-a* or on page */museum/national-museum*, which has term "city-a", I want to get the links */theater/location/city-a* and 
*/restaurant/location/city-a*.

I can get the term id on the archive page with `get_queried_object()->term_id` and on single pages with `wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'location', array( 'orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'ids' ) )` but all native wp functions allow to get the link of the terms for the current cpt only.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this?

Comment: Yes, please, I do need an answer!

Comment: Can you add your code for registering the post types and taxonomy so I can understand the URL rewrites better?

Comment: Then I'll have a go at answering.